# Google Tag Manager trigger on infinite scroll websites

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, infinite-scroll

I have a wordpress website that autoscrolls to next blog posts upon scrolling down infinitely and now looking for a way to count the next blog post load to register as a new pageview in google analytics which is setup in google tag manager

I stumbledupon this url http://www.howtofindit.in/how-to-call-tag-manager-code-in-infinite-scroll-website-pages/ BUT the article is poorly written and lack a proper step by step approach to follow without any confusion

Anyone know of a good step by step approach to follow to implement this?
so i can start tracking all blog page loads as pageviews in my google analytics

Just wanted to add that when the next blog post loads on the website i want to track, the page url changes to show the new blog post
so maybe that me be a good info to add here

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article seems a bit outdated. While the suggested approach will still be working you should be able to solve this with the (relatively new) [visibility trigger](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/element-visibility-trigger-google-tag-manager/).

So you'd go to triggers, new, select "visibility", and as a selector you enter an element that indicates a new article - say if every blog post starts with a second level heading then you enter "h2" in the box for the selector. You need to set this to "fire every time", and "observe DOM changes" (if your posts are dynamically loaded, which they probably are).

Set up a Universal Analytics tag of the pageview type and connect it to the trigger. In "Advanced/Set Fields" you need to overwrite the "page" field (else you will get the same Url for each of your virtual pageviews). The properties of the last element that fired the visibility trigger will show up in the built-in "Click" variables (don't be bothered by the name, that's for historic reasons), so you could access the headline text in the "Click Text" variable (probably you want to format it to a more url-like format).

Save, publish, and you should be good to go.

Comment: how do i do this if `post` pages are different from homepage? the css selectors are different between post page and homepage

Comment: The visibility trigger accepts a list of selectors (as comma separated list, so you can just enter both selectors and it will use the appropriate one.

Comment: done...works like a champ now...thanks for pointing to the article and your comment also helped